# Does Hazelcast always deserialize when calling IMap.get()?

Tags: hazelcast

I've got an app that needs to fetch an object out of a distributed cache several thousand times per second. I've been using Hazelcast's IMap.get(), but it seems that when I call it, my object's deserialization code gets called as well. We can't afford the overhead of deserializing over and over.

Is there a way to get Hazelcast to hold the fully formed object instead of an array of bytes?

(I would have sent this to the Hazelcast mailing list, but Google groups is refusing to let me post.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no, there's no way to prevent the deserialization of a byte array on every access (with one minor exception, see below.)

In order for Hazelcast to share your objects with other nodes in the cluster, it must pass around serialized versions of those objects as arrays of bytes.  So every time you call `IMap.get(key)` Hazelcast is going to retrieve the array of bytes representing your object from whichever node owns it and deserialize it to create a cloned copy of the object.  There is no way get around this and still have a distributed map that remains consistent across multiple nodes in the cluster.

There is one minor exception.  By default, IMaps will cache the actual deserialized object *for objects that are owned by the requesting node*.  This is set with the `cache-value` configuration parameter (which defaults to `true`).  However, any changes to that cached value *do not* get distributed to other nodes unless you explicitly do an `IMap.put(key, value)` (or `replace`, or `set`, or one of the variations thereof) after modifying the object.  See section 18.1, item 2 in the Hazelcast documentation.

Enabling `near-cache` for a map will save the cost of retrieving the byte array from the owning node (i.e. transferring the bytes from the owning node to the requesting node over the network) as it caches the bytes on the requesting node, but the deserialization still happens on every access.  This gives you better performance at the expense of consistency.  It's useful for retrieving objects that don't change often.

Comment: By the way, your question did eventually show up in the Google groups email list.

Comment: What if I maintain my own local cache of objects, and then use an EntryListener to keep it in sync? Any downsides to that approach?

Comment: I'm doing the same. I have 10 year old application costly to refactor and keeping local reference cache is the only was to get sane performance.